# How to use "RENAME USER" in MySQL 4.1.12?

Tags: mysql, rename

MySQL 5.1 has a `RENAME USER` feature that would do what I want. But unfortunately I'm running MySQL 4.1.12.

What I want to do is just change the host part of the username. I want to change the User name from `'myUsername'@'localhost'` to `'myUsername'@'123.45.%'`.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913984/re-assign-host-access-permission-to-mysql-user

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to inform you but the host is not a part of the username but a separate field in the mysql users table . You need either to create another user with the same username (yes it is possible) or to update the host field value of the record of that user like something:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET host = '123.45.%' WHERE user = 'myUsername';
```

Warning - this would update every record where username is equal to the given one additionally if it is needed you could specify another condition in the where clause.

Comment: Don't I have to UPDATE mysql.db as well? Certain users can only access certain DBs on that MySQL instance.

Comment: Your answer did help me figure it out though.