# MySQL credentials does not work in the workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I tried to use MS-DOS command line with `mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 3306` and able to log into `mysql>` console. Show grants command gives the following info

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `business`.* TO 'root'@'%'
```

However when I did the same with MySQL Workbench I get the following error

[image]

both tried with the same password and the service MYSQL56 is running correctly. What else could be causing this ?

**UPDATE**

The last thing I think I did was changing the user access location from `localhost` to `any`. How do I change it back through command line ?

Comment: I solved it by updating the host portion of the root user back to `localhost`. From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913984/re-assign-host-access-permission-to-mysql-user.

Answer (score 0):

Add password for root user and try connecti with password, looks like workbench cant connect with empty password, or here must be checkbox for it

Comment: The root user is already with a password. Seems like the password is wrong but that's the same password used when connecting in command line.